# Apply custom physical naming strategy on @where annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am setting up the CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy by extending PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl to append "`prefix__`" with table and column names before mapping with DB. And its worked for me incase of normal table and column names(column names annotated with `@Column, @ColumnName`) but its failing for `@Where`.

```
@Where(clause = "item__c is null")
```

For this: `item__c` is not changing to `prefix__item__c`.

Hibernate log is like `.....where ( serviceite0_.item__c is null).....`

Please suggest on this.

I have tried this usecase with spring-boot 2.0.8.RELEASE.

Application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
     naming:
       physical-strategy: com.echo.dataprovider.config.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy
       implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy.java

```
 public class CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6136290474018632737L;

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        return addPrefix(super.toPhysicalColumnName(identifier, jdbcEnv));
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        return addPrefix(super.toPhysicalTableName(identifier, jdbcEnv));
    }

    private Identifier addPrefix(final Identifier identifier) {
        return (identifier == null
                || !identifier.getText().matches("(.*)" + "__A" + "(.*)"))
                        ? identifier
                        : Identifier.toIdentifier(String.join("__B__",
                                Arrays.stream(identifier.getText().split("__B__"))
                                        .map(m -> "prefix__" + m).toArray(String[]::new)));
    }
    }
```

Model.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service__c", schema = "abc")
public class Service {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "service")
    **@Where(clause = "item__c is null")**
    private List<Item> itemList;
...
```

Expected:

```
@Where(clause = "item__c is null")
```

For this: `item__c` should change to `prefix__item__c`.

Answer (score 0):

[`@Where` javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/javadoc/):

> The clause is written in SQL

`PhysicalNamingStrategy` can be used only with JPA names. [This section of Hibenrate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html) doesn't state it explicitly, but it is pretty clear from these statements:

> JPA Compatibility
>
> JPA defines inherent rules about implicit logical name determination. If JPA provider portability is a major concern, or if you really just like the JPA-defined implicit naming rules, be sure to stick with ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl (the default)
>
> Also, JPA defines no separation between logical and physical name. Following the JPA specification, the logical name is the physical name. If JPA provider portability is important, applications should prefer not to specify a PhysicalNamingStrategy.

Unfortunately you need to use full name in `@Where` clause.